# macOS SwiftUI Button "Active Area" Width of Parent View

Tags: macos, swiftui, swiftui-button

For a macOS app, I like to extend a button's width across it's parent view using SwiftUI. I tried this:
import SwiftUI

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {print("TEST")}) {
                Image(systemName: "clock")
                    .frame(width: 25, height: 25, alignment: .center)
                Text("This is a button")
                    .frame(minWidth: 200, idealWidth: 200, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 25, idealHeight: 25, maxHeight: 25, alignment: .leading)
                Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                    .frame(width: 25, height: 25, alignment: .center)
            }
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

and it will yield a result that looks quite what I am searching, but if you click in the area marked in red in the following screenshot of the app

[image]

the buttons action does not fire. Also the area between the first image and the text does not fire the action. I also tried to implement a custom ButtonStyle but with no luck. How can I achieve a button that extends over the full width of the parent view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `.contentShape(Rectangle())`:

```
Button(action: { print("TEST") }) {
    HStack {
        // ...
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    .contentShape(Rectangle())
}
```